# How to transform list of texts into Mallet Corpus?

Tags: python, nlp, lda, gensim, mallet

I have a large corpus of texts represented as list of texts:

[text1, text2, ..., textn]

I also have a list of names of these texts:

[text1_name, text2_name, ..., textn_name]

How do I turn such data into Mallet Corpus?
So that it could be possible to use LDA from gensim?

```
from gensim.models.ldamulticore import LdaMulticore
corpus = gensim.corpora.MalletCorpus( **what_should_stay_here??** )
lda = LdaMulticore(corpus, workers = -1)
```